# Is it possible to export an Orchard Theme without using the command line?

Tags: orchardcms

I have next to no experience with Orchard, or .NET in general for that matter, but I have agreed to do some development on an existing Orchard website.

I have an admin-login with access to the Dashboard and I have an admin-login at the hosting provider (Arvixe). I've started moving the site over to Azure so I can use that as a staging environment.

I've successfully exported all the content, but the site is also running a custom theme that I also need to move over. From what I gather the only way to package that theme is using the command line interface, but I can't find a way to run the command line executable via the hosting provider's web interface (I haven't been able to connect to it with SSH).

Is there any way to run what is usually command line operations via the Dashboard? Some kind of module that I have not discovered? Is there any way of moving a theme from one installation to another without using the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the Arvixe account, you also have access to ftp. Do that, then look under the Themes directory. Copy the theme's folder. What's the web site?

Comment: I tried to copy over a folder under Themes called `TheThemeMachine` or something like that. It contained css and js that I've seen on the site so I guess that was the correct one. Theme showed up in Dashboard but the application crashed when I tried to view it. I'll try to locate the logs but I guess that is going to be a separate issue. So I'm accepting this answer.